# Using Tagged Branches in Master for Production

Tags: git, github

We are tagging our commits in our codebase, which are in branches, for example `release-1.1`, and merging them to `master` when we are finished working on them. Can we pick those tags to create a release *from* `master` and push out to our production environment?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you naming the branches the way described or are you tagging `commits in the branches`? And my question. What you want to achieve is that you want only specific commits from master to be picked into release branch?

Comment: My apologise, it's commits, I have amended. Also, what I need to achieve is so we can release specific commits to Production... We have a rolling release process, sometimes stuff that doesn't need releasing gets released...

Comment: It sounds like you should just create your release from the Tag you want to release.

Comment: Yes, that's it, how do I do that?